# ionic 4 routerOutlet.canGoBack() returns false when navigating with navigateForward

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a button in my ionic application to open a article from the homepage. I want to enable my users to exit the app by pressing the device back button.  But when they are at the article page I want it to just go back to the homepage when pressing the back button.

I created a custom backbutton event to handle the function of exiting the app. It can exit the app from the homepage. However when pressing the back button on the article page, it does not navigate back to the homepage and nothing happens.  How can I make it goes back to the homepage from the article page when pressing the back button?

In app.component.ts

```
this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(99, async () => {
  if (this.routerOutlet && this.routerOutlet.canGoBack()) {
      this.routerOutlet.pop();
  } else if (this.router.url === '/home') {
      navigator['app'].exitApp();
  }
});
```

I noticed that this.routerOutlet.canGoBack returns false when firing the event from the article page, so the routerOutlet.pop() is not fired.  Not sure if this is to do with how I open the article page?

This is how i open the article page

```
viewArticle(articleId) {
  let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
    state: {
      articleId: articleId
    }
  };
  this.navController.navigateForward(['/article'], navigationExtras);
}
```

Comment: Any updates in this question? Please share your solution if you achieved it in a different way. Thank you!

Comment: Please share if you found the solution.